# how to debug trampling issues in linux

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am facing issues with memory trampling in a large software.

Sometimes SIGSEGV/SIGABRT is getting observed.Reason is mainly trampling on the user or malloc space memory.Tried with mprotect-ed memory as a "bait" but no luck .
Not able to catch the trampler actually.From core file analysis it seems that corruption is happening also in malloc space (current chunk size). Corruption always is of single byte and happens anywhere (I mean so such pattern that I can call it a overflow/underflow , like 0xFF00FF00 is corrupted with 0xFF003A00)

Any suggestion on the possible investigation ways ??

P.S -- Not possible to attach valgrind.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Why are you immediately ruling out what may be your best possible option on a Linux system (valgrind)?

Comment: tried that .. but the nature of application such that we are not able to bind valgrind with it ..

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of tricks that you can try. First off, check the heap for consistency see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html#Heap-Consistency-Checking).

You might also want to write a hook where you write DEDEDEDE to all freed memory see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html#Hooks-for-Malloc) on writing a hook to do just that .

Comment: tried those actually . even if the signature is corrupted , there is no way to catch the trampler .... wanted some suggestion to catch the corrupted itself..

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of alternative heap implementations with various forms of sanity checking  that you link against your system in place of the one in libc.   Common techniques include:

- Allocating larger blocks than requesting and placing guard-zones around the beginning and end of the requested block
- One-page per allocation, with inaccessible pages either side (e.g. page fault on any access)
- Tracking allocated blocks as well as deallocated ones
- Walking the heap in a low priority thread looking for bad stuff

I spent a very long time trying to find such a problem a few years ago on an embedded system -  one that was reported after several days of uptime.  Never got the unit on my desk to crash.  I tried pretty much every trick in the book - including a thorough code audit and PCLinting the entire code-base.

I eventually tracked the cause down to the wrong speed grade of SDRAM on both systems.  The one that crashed was slightly more marginal than the one on my desk.  Eventually proved conclusively with a hair-dryer and a can of freezer-spray :/

If you can get a confirmed location that gets repeatedly trampled,  you next port of call will be to use either hardware assisted debugging (most CPUs allow this these days) or a ICE or JTAG-based debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If by some miracle you can somehow make the same memory location get corrupted on consecutive runs (or at least 25% of the time or something) you can use a data breakpoint in gdb on that memory location.

If that's not happening, have you tried your S/W on different hardware to rule out a hardware memory error? While rare such things can still occur.

Another options is to try preloading an allocator such as `libumem` or google's allocator and see if it can detect any memory problems.

I know you said this wasn't an option, but if you can narrow down the problem in any way to a smaller set of code, `valgrind` really is that good - it's helped me on multiple occasions.

Finally if none of those options yield fruit you're going to have to go more heavyweight:

- If you can check the sanity of your data structures in some way, litter your code with such checks.
- Start removing code and see if the problem goes away.
- Refactor or rewrite suspect parts of the code from scratch.
- Multi-person peer reviews of any/all code in the affected areas. Preferably one person has good familiarity with the code while the other person has domain knowledge but *doesn't* know the code (because when you don't know what you think the code says, you see bugs a lot easier as you review).